# Reducing a Matrix with Guass-Jordan elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I am doing some homework, but I am stuck on this problem.

> 1. $-x+y=-2$
> 2. $-3x+2z=13$
> 3. $2x-2z=-6$

Here's my work:

[image]

That wasn't accepted.  I then threw it in matlab, to try to work my way towards the right answer, and got $(-1, -3, -2)$ and that wasn't right either.  Further, I found a matrix calculator online and that gave a different answer that was wrong also.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong in the above picture?

Comment: in the first matrix, second row, the -3 is the coefficient of $x$, not of $y$, so shouldn't it be on the first column?

Comment: Apparently, I make a lot of mistakes. Ha!  I made a mistake typing it in here.  It was -3y.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-6+(-2)(2) = -10$, not $2$.

Simple arithmetical error in bottom right entry in first line.

Comment: Oh man.  Thanks a lot.  I feel stupid. Ha!

Comment: no prob, i'd imagine that everyone on this website has - at some point - posted a question an then felt really stupid